# How to read different property files for different environment?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a web application created in maven. I am using tomcat server on my local as well as on dev unix box. I need to use two different .properties file like local.properties and dev.properties (may be in different folders). My doubt is 'How can we configure the tomcat of local and the tomcat of unix box to read different properties file at the time of deployment?' What are different ways for it.

Comment: I downvote because it appears no attempt was made : http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ . I suggest you to take few minutes to read : [How do I ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question might better be asked a https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and out of the box solution you can use with spring is to have two files, named `application-dev.properties` and `application-prod.properties` which will be activated if if you pass `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` or `prod`. You pass this parameter when deploying the app. No configuration, no annotation, no xml. As long as you keep the naming convention `application-something.properties`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is pass a system parameter to your JVM to identify the environment, then package up a dev.properties and local.properties in the jar.

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:local.properties", "classpath:${ENVX}.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

Use a -DENVX=dev for dev (add to your tomcat script), if it is not specified local.properties will be picked up.